# Either Sign Up and Log In should lead to different pages or one of those links should be removed

Tags: feature-request, login, sign-up

When I tried to log in I noticed that Sign Up and Login will both bring you to this page :

[image]

Why would this page show up if I already clicked that I want to sign up ?

I says skip this page and bring me to the sign up section. Or remove one of the two buttons.

Comment: "Do you already have an account on one of these sites? Click the logo to log in with it here: ". You can one click sign up using one of these services there.

Comment: @zch Ok so why two buttons for it. Might as well put one that says get in. I know it is conventional to have a sign up and login button but it is also bad to have two buttons next to each other that have the exact same behaviour.

Comment: I agree, I would kill "sign up" button (and "tour" too, to make things more consistent).

Comment: @Anna thanks that was the next step. Cant get more specific :P

Comment: If either were removed then users would search for it. Unless the one remaining button was renamed 'sign up/log in'

Comment: Y'know, I often find myself needing to view that page just to recall which login options are featured by default. I think we need a third link: [show me the login options](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These links will very shortly be different pages.  We will be rolling out a new, very simplified, design for the login and sign-up pages using SSL after the holidays.